# Как исправить ошибку Undefined offset: 0 in capabilities.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт WordPress + WooCommerce. Появилась нужда создать мультисайт. Я создал по инструкции. На главном сайте появилась ошибка
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\OpenServer\domains\pizza2.loc\wp-includes\capabilities.php on line 68

вот кусок кода из файла:

```
// In multisite the user must have manage_network_users caps. If editing a super admin, the user must be a super admin.
      if ( is_multisite() && ( ( ! is_super_admin( $user_id ) && 'edit_user' === $cap && is_super_admin( $args[0] ) ) || ! user_can( $user_id, 'manage_network_users' ) ) ) {
        $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
      } else {
        $caps[] = 'edit_users'; // edit_user maps to edit_users.
      }
```

В чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а поговорить?)

Comment: WooCommerce не предназначен для мультисайта, вообще-то. Есть сильно платное расширение.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как и твой комментарий собстна

Comment: @KAGG Design, спасибо, отрубил все плагины, проблема ушла, буду разбираться и искать решения, спасибо)

Comment: @РоманЧенский Мой комментарий имеет смысл, потому что даёт понимание, что в вопросе важна суть, а не предыстория о том, как ты родился

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну в целом, ты мог бы объяснить и первую часть вопроса, если ты не увидел 2 проблемы, одна основная, и второстепенная, которую я попробую решить сам, но было бы круто получить и консультация по нему - твоя проблема. Так что коммент несет меньше смысла, чем предыстория

Comment: Прежде чем спорить, стоит почитать правила. Один пост - один вопрос.

Comment: @KAGG Design, 
*помочь разобраться в теме
-неее
*написать тучу душных комментов, о том что автор не так пишет 
-дааа
За помощь спасибо, дело не в вукомерс, в другом плагине

Answer (score 0):

Все, нормально, дело в плагине "DIGITS: регистрация и вход в WordPress через номер мобильного" буду искать альтернативное решение для регистрации через смс, спасибо)